# fopen() function does not work as expected on my friends PC

Tags: c

I have written the following file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "config.h"

FILE* fptr;

void writeConfig(const char* new_api_key) {
    if ((fptr = fopen("../config.txt", "w")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error creating config file");
    } else {
        fprintf(fptr, "%s", new_api_key);
        fclose(fptr);
    }
}

char* readConfig(char* buffer, size_t bufSize) {
    if ((fptr = fopen("../config.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        return "error opening config file";
    } else {
        if ((fgets(buffer, bufSize, fptr)) == NULL) {
            fclose(fptr);
            return "error reading config file";
        }
        else {
            fclose(fptr);
            return buffer;
        }
    }
}
```

And on 3 different tested machines this code works. But on one of my friends PC it does not.
The code gets executed as following:

```
    char buffer[50];
    long long bufSize = 50;
    char* message = "example123";

    writeConfig(message);
    printf(readConfig(buffer, bufSize));
```

As seen in the "writeConfig" function, this creates a new txt file named "config.txt" and then tries to read it via the "readConfig" function. Weird is, that the "writeConfig" function does not throw an error, even tho the file is not created in his case. Only the "readConfig" function throws the error "error opening config file" which means that fopen() returned NULL.
We have also tried manually creating the config.txt file but the code still failed at the "readConfig" function with the same error.
I have the feeling that it could be about some read and write permissions? But i can not come up with a solution.
(Both PC run Windows)
Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: This could happen if the file has write-only permission. What does `ls -l ../config.txt` show?

Comment: When `fopen()` fails, you should print the reason, not just a generic "error opening" message. Use `perror()` to print the error message from `errno`.

Comment: Since ls does not work on windows without wsl we searched it the windows way and did not found any file.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/364083/windows-list-files-and-their-permissions-access-in-command-line

Comment: @Barmar seems like it is not so easy to log the error message, because my programm is a plugin (DLL) for Teamspeak and I can not see the logs I print out. So using perror is not an option because I am not able to see that log :/
(Or is there a way to still see that log that I do not know?)

Comment: How are you seeing `Error opening config file`?

Comment: write config does not close the file

Comment: @Barmar I am using a teamspeak plugin sdk which provides a function to print Strings as a "Log" into the Chat.

Comment: @0___________ you are right, I fixed that.

Comment: @0___________ It calls `fclose()` on the line after `fprintf()`

Comment: You can use `printf("Error opening config file: %s", strerror(errno));` to print the error message.

Comment: @Barmar that is a great advice! I will try that :)